# Read Only cell in DataGridView in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm want to make only one cell in a datagridview to be readonly and I have tried the following methods, but none of them were successfully.

```
dgv_parametersetting(2, 0).ReadOnly = True
dgv_parametersetting.Rows(0).Cells(2).ReadOnly = True

For Each r As DataGridViewRow In dgv_parametersetting.Rows
      If r.Cells(2).Value = 0 Then
           r.Cells(2).ReadOnly = True
      End If
Next
```

Can anyone please provide me with the syntax to make a specific cell in the datagridview view read-only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try this - code from Code Project-:

```
   Private Sub dgv_CellBeginEdit(sender As Object, e As  DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellBeginEdit

 If e.RowIndex = 0 And e.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
    e.Cancel = True
 End If

End Sub
```

Comment: this worked as excepted by preventing the user from entering the cell

Answer (score 0):

Never tried the ReadOnly property, but you could achive the same via the CellValidating-event I suppose. Use your code above + e.Cancel

Answer (score 0):

You can handel the event `RowsAdded`  like :

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_RowsAdded(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs)
Handles DataGridView1.RowsAdded
 If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 AndAlso DataGridView1.ColumnCount >= 2 Then
    DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).ReadOnly = True
 End If
 End Sub
```